# How to assign a read line to a String variable using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java

I have a text file with one line. I want to read it using Java 8 `Stream` and assign the read line to a `String` variable.

I'm stuck here

```
    public String getParamFromFile() {
    String param = "";
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("./resources/price.txt"))) {
        param = stream.forEach(); //how to assign the read line to this field?
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return param;
}
```

Comment: Just use `Files.readAllLines` and get the first element of the returned `List`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : It says `The resource type List<String> does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable`

  try (List<String> stream = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("./resources/price.txt"))) {
   
  }

Comment: You don't need the `try-with-resources` from your current snippet. You'll want  a simple `try-catch` around the `readAllLines` call, since it declares `IOException` as a potential thrown exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Got it. Thanks. It works. however I Don't need a `List`. If I get it as a `List` I have to `Iterate` and get the values.

Comment: If you know you have one line (or if you don't, check), just `allLines.get(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just get the first element of the stream by doing,

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("./resources/price.txt"))).findFirst().get()
```

The `findFirst` method returns an `Optional<String>` type rather than `null` if there isn't a first line. You can assign a default value if there isn't a first line in the file by doing,

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("./resources/price.txt"))).findFirst().orElse("default string")
```